# Combine two specific javascript functions into one function for desired effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I combine two specific javascript functions into one function for the desired effect? or if anyone has a different solution I am open to it.

Here is the JS/Jquery to make the page scroll to an href anchor url using jquery.easing.1.3.js

```
    $(function() {
           $('a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Here is an older JS to hide/show a series of divs only allowing one div to show at any given time.

```
function NavigateSpecs(thechosenspec) {
    var SPEC = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var x=0; x<SPEC.length; x++) {
        name = SPEC[x].getAttribute("name");
        if (name == 'SPEC-2') {
              if (SPEC[x].id == thechosenspec) {
                    if (SPEC[x].style.display == 'block') {
                          SPEC[x].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else {
                          SPEC[x].style.display = 'block';
                    }
              }else {
                    SPEC[x].style.display = 'none';
              }
        }
     }
    }
```

I need to combine these two functions so upon clicking a link the browser will scroll to the desired anchor like the first JS function and show the specific div while hiding any other div with the similar id structure.

Comment: Would just placing them into a function that calls both of them work: `masterFunction(arg) { func1(); func2(); }`?

Comment: What arguments would I need to pass or how would I put the arguments in a link to pass the arguments to each script function? the link to show the div is this - <a id="mySpec1-2" href="javascript:NavigateSpecs('SPEC1-2');"> Where would the anchor link be referenced?

Comment: Just do it the same way for `NavigateSpecs(thechosenspec)`. Seems like you only need that single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for me. I'll take a deeper look into it if it fails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(e) {
        $('a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

            function NavigateSpecs(thechosenspec) {
            var SPEC = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var x=0; x<SPEC.length; x++) {
            name = SPEC[x].getAttribute("name");
            if (name == 'SPEC-2') {
            if (SPEC[x].id == thechosenspec) {
            if (SPEC[x].style.display == 'block') {
            SPEC[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
            SPEC[x].style.display = 'block';
            }
            }else {
            SPEC[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
            }
            }
            }

        event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Whats the point of defining a function so far in scope and not executing it? What if the user wants to call `NavigateSpecs()`?

Comment: Normally the user clicks an href to activate the anchor which determines the scroll destination <a href="#anchorName">. In the case of NavigateSpecs() the href is the javascript function <a id="mySpec1-2" href="javascript:NavigateSpecs('SPEC1-2');"> - so how would the anchor be identified along with the specs window id which needs to be changed?   example - <a name="Spec1-2" href="#anchorName"> I don't think this will work.